# Compare two files and write the unmatched numbers in a new file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, diff

I have two files where ifile1.txt is a subset of ifile2.txt.

```
ifile1.txt   ifile2.txt
    2            2
    23           23
    43           33
    51           43
    76           50
    81           51
   100           72
                 76
                 81
                 89
                100
```

Desire output

```
ofile.txt
   33
   50
   72
   89
```

I was trying with

```
diff ifile1.txt ifile2.txt > ofile.txt
```

but it is giving different format of output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your files are sorted, you can use the [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) command for this:

```
comm -1 -3 ifile1.txt ifile2.txt > ofile.txt
```

`-1` means omit the lines unique to the first file, and `-3` means omit the lines that are in both files, so this shows just the lines that are unique to the second file.

Answer (score 1):

This will do your job:

```
diff file1 file2 |awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
diff file1 file2 | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v '^$' > output.file
```